# Cannot figure out Fluentvalidation error with array

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluentvalidation

I am having some problems with Fluentvalidation.  Here is my method I wish to unit test,

```
public IEnumerable<PingOptions> MostRecentPings()
        {
            IEnumerable<PingOptions> pingOptions = new[]
            {
                new PingOptions()
                {
                    DontFragment = true,
                    Ttl = 1
                },
                new PingOptions()
                {
                    DontFragment = true,
                    Ttl = 1
                },
                new PingOptions()
                {
                    DontFragment = true,
                    Ttl = 1
                },
            };
            return pingOptions;
        }
```

Here is my Fluentvalidation unit test,

```
        [Fact]
        public void NetworkService_MostRecientPings_ReturnesOobject()
        {
            // Arrange
            var expected = new PingOptions()
            {
                DontFragment = true,
                Ttl = 1
            };

            // Act
            var result = _pingService.MostRecentPings();

            // Assert
            result.Should().BeOfType<IEnumerable<PingOptions>>();
            result.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(expected);
            result.Should().Contain(x => x.DontFragment == true);
        }
```

Fluent fails the first should statement "result.Should().BeOfType<IEnumerable>();"  The failure return says,

```
NetworkUtility.Tests.PingTests.NetworkServiceTests.NetworkService_MostRecientPings_ReturnesOobject
   Source: NetworkServiceTests.cs line 92
   Duration: 78 ms

  Message: 
Expected type to be System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions, System.Net.Ping, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]], but found System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions[].

  Stack Trace: 
XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String message)
TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
AssertionScope.FailWith(String message)
TypeAssertions.Be(Type expected, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
ReferenceTypeAssertions`2.BeOfType(Type expectedType, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
ReferenceTypeAssertions`2.BeOfType[T](String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
NetworkServiceTests.NetworkService_MostRecientPings_ReturnesOobject() line 107
```

I have tried defining result as an array with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you expect the result to be of type IEnumerable, but the actual result type is an array of PingOptions[].

Try to change your assertion to check for the actual type of result, like this:

`result.Should().BeOfType<PingOptions[]>();`

Comment: Another option would be to use `BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<PingOptions>>`